# robots.txt to allow adsense bot

Tags: adsense, robots.txt

What should I add in my robots.txt file so that adsense bot do not face any problem to cral my site?
In Google support (http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10532) it is recommended to add following lines

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google 
Disallow:
```

But in many online sources and even in Wikipedia the suggested lines are :

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Disallow:
```

Can anybody clear me please, do I need to add " * " and what is the perpous of adding this " * " sign? And if it is important then why Google has not mentioned it to add * in its support page?

Comment: You don't need to add anything to allow a bot to crawl your site. Unless you specifically block a bot, it assumes that it can crawl. (Absent a directive that blocks all bots, of course.)

Comment: Where did you find the line `Mediapartners-Google*`?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that your file has the wrong name. It should be `robots.txt`. The asterisk is not nessesary because you know the exact name of the User-Agent.

Comment: The asterisk  is in general just a placeholder for all crawlers (`User-agent: *`).

Comment: but why did WordPress Community suggest to add "*" ?? http://codex.wordpress.org/Search_Engine_Optimization_for_WordPress

Comment: Maybe bacause they don't have rules for seperate crawlers. E.g. you have a crowler you want to block. Than you can set allow all crawlers but not bot XYZ. You could also have a look for the robots.txt of [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt).

Answer (score 0):

That interesting ubiquous star * is everywhere :D :D

But Google Webmastertools robots.txt checker does not like it.

For example this does not allow Adsense bot as it should, at least according to the testing tool, 2013 03:

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Disallow:
```

This works in the checker:

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:
```

Was encouraged to test it myself by http://drupal.org/node/572926